# jquery .post event firing incrementally

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, .post

I'm trying to make a comments-system on my site. I manage the ajax part and the comment is submitted from the form to the called php-file which then stores the data in mysql db. After storing the data is appended to the allready existing comments.

The problem I have is that if you post another comment after a previous one fomr the same page, the next comment is added twice. Do it again and the next one is added three times and so on. I guess I got the jquery wrong somewhere but can't seem to find it.

Here's the form I'm using :

```
    <form class="short style" id="postnewscomment" name="postnewscomment" onsubmit="javascript:postnewscomments();">
    <textarea style="width:95%;" name="commenttext" required data-required="true" placeholder="Uw comment" /></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="addcomment" />
    <input type="hidden" name="postername" value="<? echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="newsid" value="<? echo $newsid; ?>" />
    <div class="button">
        <button value="postnews" name="Submit" type="submit">Add Comment</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Here's my jquery code that is called by the form :

```
function postnewscomments() {
    $("#postnewscomment").submit(function(e){    
        e.preventDefault();  
    var hasError = false;
        var url = "postnewscomments.php";
    var texttopost =    "#postnewscomment"; 
    if(hasError == false) {
        $.post(url, $(texttopost).serialize() ,function(data) {
            $(data).hide().appendTo("#newscomment").fadeIn(1000);
        // code to reset form values to empty
                $( '#postnewscomment' ).each(function(){
                this.reset();
        });
             });
    }
     return false;
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `submit()` method:

> Bind an event handler to the "submit" JavaScript event, or trigger
>   that event on an element.

so It should be called only once (when the page loads) and not on every submit.

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: changed it to '$(window).bind("load", function() {
    postnewscomments();
});' and that did the trick ! Can't believe how simple it was, and that I didn't find this earlier ... Still new to JS and Jquery, but it's not easy starting out :( Thx for the help !